# DirectX 11 Drawing Circles

Tags: directx, directx-11, hlsl

I am trying to draw points with various thickness. I was using triangle method but resulting circles had jagged edges.I had to quit this method due to performance issues and visual quality goals of my app. I saw Pixel Shader method [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xf7Y988cPRk). My problem with this method is my point thickness values are not in pixels.They are in meters. Do I have to convert back to World coordinates in pixel shader to measure distance from center? Or, is there another approach to overcome coordinate conversion process?

My attempt:

Topology

```
dxmanager->Context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);
```

Vertex Shader

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float size : RSIZE;   
};

VOut main(float3 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR, float size: RSIZE)
{
    VOut output;
    output.position = float4(position, 1);
    output.color = color;
    output.size = size;

    return output;
}
```

Pixel Shader

```
float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR, float4 centre : POSITION,float max:RSIZE) : SV_TARGET
{
    if (distance(position,centre)<max) // Always False
        return color;
    return float4(0, 0, 0, 0);    
}
```

Geometry Shader

```
[maxvertexcount(6)]
void main(point VOut input[1], inout TriangleStream<GOut> OutputStream)
{

    GOut P1;
    P1.pos = float4(input[0].position.x-input[0].size/2, input[0].position.y - input[0].size/2, input[0].position.z,1);
    P1.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P1.pos = mul(world, P1.pos);
    P1.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P1.max = input[0].size * scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P1);

    GOut P2;
    P2.pos = float4(input[0].position.x - input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.y + input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.z, 1);
    P2.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P2.pos = mul(world, P2.pos);
    P2.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P2.max = input[0].size*scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P2);

    GOut P3;
    P3.pos = float4(input[0].position.x + input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.y - input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.z, 1);
    P3.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P3.pos = mul(world, P3.pos);
    P3.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P3.max = input[0].size * scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P3);

    GOut P4;
    P4.pos = float4(input[0].position.x + input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.y + input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.z, 1);
    P4.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P4.pos = mul(world, P4.pos);
    P4.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P4.max = input[0].size * scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P4);

    GOut P5;
    P5.pos = float4(input[0].position.x + input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.y - input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.z, 1);
    P5.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P5.pos = mul(world, P5.pos);
    P5.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P5.max = input[0].size * scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P5);

    GOut P6;
    P6.pos = float4(input[0].position.x - input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.y - input[0].size / 2, input[0].position.z, 1);
    P6.color = float4(0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    P6.pos = mul(world, P6.pos);
    P6.centre = mul(world, input[0].position);
    P6.max = input[0].size * scale;
    OutputStream.Append(P6);
}
```

Comment: You could use Direct2D (over Direct3D11) that has has many 2D features, such as geometries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-geometries-overview

Comment: Sadly, I have to use some Direct3D11 features so I can't switch to Direct2D.

Comment: You ask for another approach, Direct2D is part of the same DirectX technology and ships with Windows. What do you mean by "I have to use some Direct3D11 features".

Comment: I am looking for better approach than "Converting back to World coordinates in pixel shader".  About Direct3D11, Zooming is the one of the features Direct2D can't handle well.

Comment: I can't watch the video you've shared right now, but fundamentally there's no issue with drawing circles in a pixel shader. Drawing a circle using a shader is usually just as simple as using Pythagoras (with some extra code needed for antialiasing), so you just need to determine the distance from the center in whatever coordinate system you are using.

Comment: You are right but the problem is how do i determine the distance? Pixel shader inputs SV_POSITION. Another problem is topology set to POINTLIST. I don't have TEXCOOR (Most of the answers about this question uses TEXCOOR and they don't cover rest of the solution.).

Comment: I can't speak to the specific problems that come with using DirectX, but you should just be able to multiply your coordinates by some conversion factor so they are all the same unit, then compute the distance. I don't know where TEXCOOR ties into this, but texture coordinates are not dependent on unit sizes so you shouldn't need to do anything special with that?

Comment: In pixel shader, anything other than SV_POSITION and COLOR appears to be zero. So I can't convert them to same coordinate system.

Comment: About jagged edges, do you have msaa enabled? That normally helps a lot for those cases.

Comment: yes but jagged edges appears because of low triangle count. I can't increase them due to performance reasons. If I increase triangle count, Rendering ~100M points are going to be a disaster even on brand new cards.